# Is there a way to password protect multiples excel files within R

Tags: r, password-protection

I have written a script in R that split up a large CSV into multiples excel files based on the name of the customer and want to password protect them. I have another file with the name and the associated password.
I have previously try the xlsx package with the password argument but not sucess.
Any advice would be much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: can you add the code you've tried and elaborate on 'not success'?

Comment: openxlsx package can do this: https://rdrr.io/github/awalker89/openxlsx/man/protectWorkbook.html

Comment: @Khaynes, while the function exists, I just tested the example code and am not prompted for a password. (This is a bug for awalker95, not you, I'm just advising that that solution may not work for everybody.)

Comment: Chesou, perhaps you should consider "why" you want to do this. Password protection on an xlsx is relatively trivial to break (I'm not going to search or encourage that here), but will primarily "keep the honest out". If you have real protection requirements, then you might need to investigate other methods.

Comment: Thank you  all for the support and different ideas. @RAB my initial script takes a CSV and split it up based on the customer field and write them in excel. I was trying to assign an password to each file based on another customer list in which some conditions needed to be met but I was able to sort it out by doing a for loop.

Comment: @r2evans I agree with the idea but this seems to be fine for now as it is just what I need. Thanks